# How to Play YouTube Video from Desired Point in Timeline by Giving Video URL

Tags: jquery, html

I have some video files stored on my local server. I want playback to start from a specific point in the video by giving a user a video URL with a second value appended. 
Are there any jquery libraries that offer this?

An Example of what I'm looking for (from YouTube):
youtube.com/watch?v=PjDw3azfZWI&start=15

The above link will cause the video to start playing 15 seconds in.

Comment: Has anyone really been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/)

I believe this has the ability to specify a start point via URL.